# Akka and blocked parallel processing

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I have a situation where I need to start a background process, and monitor if it has started. The manager actor starts a TCP connection. The data coming from the TCP connection is put into a non-blocking queue and is processed by a separate thread (needs to be separate as it takes a lot of processing power and the data comes in continuously, 30 times a second).

I created a monitor actor and a manager actor. I first start the monitor actor, which waits for the processing thread to notify if data is coming in and is successfully processing. However, the problem is that the manager actor only start once getting the result of the monitoring actor times out. So the monitoring actor is blocking the the manager actor.

How can I prevent that from happening, and have the monitoring tread not block?

```
@Override
public boolean initialise(ActorSystem system) throws StreamingException {
    port = Integer.parseInt(source.getParameter("port"));
    ipAddress = source.getParameter("ipAddress");

    try {
        lastResultMonitorActor = system.actorOf(Q16ResultMonitorActor.props());
        CompletableFuture<String> future = ask(lastResultMonitorActor, Q16MonitoringEnum.INIT , Duration.ofSeconds(10)).thenApplyAsync(response -> (String) response).toCompletableFuture();
        getManagerActorRef().tell(Q16MonitoringEnum.VERSION_REQUEST, ActorRef.noSender());
        
        String version = future.get();
        isReady = version.length() > 0;
        logger.info("Qu16 connection ready: " + isReady);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        if (e.getCause().getClass() == AskTimeoutException.class) {
            logger.debug("Time-out, the mixer might be off: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new StreamingException("No response from the Qu16 mixer, is it on?", StreamingStatus.AUDIO_SOURCE_NOT_RESPONDING, e);
        } else {
            logger.debug("ExecutionException on QU 16 request: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new StreamingException("Communication issue with the Qu16 mixer, is it on?", StreamingStatus.AUDIO_SOURCE_NOT_RESPONDING, e);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        isReady = false;
        throw new StreamingException("Problem initiating the audio source: " + e.getMessage(), AUDIO_SOURCE_WARNING, e);
    }
    return isReady;
}
```

Comment: One obvious smell is the `future.get()` call that will block the current thread. If that thread is one of the akka's dispatcher threads then that's your culprit. How do you call the `initialise` method? from another actor? To solve this instead of returning `boolean` from your method, return `CompletableFuture<Boolean>` and instead of blocking the future by calling `get()` use `thenApply` and other methods from `CompletionStage`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I should have stated that it only blocks in certain situations, so maybe when there is not enough threads in the akka pool and the new actor is waiting. I will see if I can make an adjustment to the default configuration but also review the passing on the CompletionStage.

Comment: No. Don't adjust the configuration. Making blocking calls like that is going to cause problems and trying to tweak the thread configuration is like applying a band aid to an axe wound. Do what artur said: change it something that handles the Future asynchronously and pipe a message back to the actor if necessary.

Comment: Thanks David, yes, I did implement it properly with callbacks and thenApply, and now it works as expected.

Comment: Be certain that when you are in the thenApply to not modify the actor's state. The Future will likely be on a different thread. If you need to update the actor's state use the thenApply to send a message back to the actor.